# pdfx package gives me Option clash for package hyperref

Tags: option-clash, pdfx

I'm using the following package for convert a PDF to a PDF/A format

```
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
```

When I compile, I receive the following error.

> "Option clash for package hyperref"

I've searched within TEX but until now I didn't find any valid solution.

I compile with Mac OS Tex in TexShop. The typeset is set as LaTex.

Thank you in advance.

*Edit*

Here a small example of what I'm trying to achieve

```
\documentclass[english,lof,lot]{thesis} 
\errorcontextlines=9

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Added Packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{float}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PDF/A
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

// begin document here...
```

where thesis.cls is a document class that contains the following

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \RequirePackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\else
  \RequirePackage{hyperref}
\fi
```

Since I didn't write the class, I would like to know if how is it possible to overcome the error.

When I try to compile with this configuration, the error is the following

> The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
>   [pdfpagelabels].
>   There has now been an attempt to load with option
>   [pdftex,pdfa] Adding the global options:pdfpagelabels,pdftex,pdfa to
>   your \documentclass declaration may fix this.

Comment: if you type h to the prompt it should tell you which option clashed and suggest a possible workaround

Comment: The package `pdfx` already loads `hyperref`; if you need to set other options for this one, use `\hypersetup{<options>}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. The compiler gives me: *The package hyperref has already been loaded with options: [pdfpagelabels] There has now been an attempt to load with option [pdftex,latex] Adding the global options:pdfpagelabels,pdftex,pdfa to your \documentclass declaration may fix this*

Comment: @egreg Thank you. What do you mean with your comment? I'm not very expert about this.

Comment: On the next line it will have said `Adding the global options:...
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.` add the options it says to `\documentclass` (this can fail but it works in most cases)

Comment: Do I need to add the three options? See my edited comment. Thanks.

Comment: @flexaddicted Please, add a small example of what you're trying to do. However, saying `\usepackage[pdftex,latex]{hyperref}` is useless when `pdfx` has already been loaded. In general, the option `pdftex` shouldn't be specified and `latex` is not a recognized option.

Comment: @egreg sorry my fault. It's [pdftex,pdfa] and not the previous one

Comment: @flexaddicted Well, it's useless anyway.

Comment: @egreg I added an example. Could you help me to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @egreg comment

> The package pdfx already loads hyperref; if you need to set other
>   options for this one, use \hypersetup{options here}

I removed this code in the class file

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \RequirePackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\else
  \RequirePackage{hyperref}
\fi
```

and in .tex file I did the following

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PDF/A
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\hypersetup{pdfpagelabels}
```

Now it compiles and when I open it trough Adobe, it says me that is PDF/A compliant.

I think this works since I compile through PdfLaTex, but I'm not sure. I'm not an expert on this.

**If exists a better solution, let me know. I will try it and remove the mark for my answer**.

P.S. @Herbert, thank you for the support.

Answer (score 5):

that should be

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf \PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels}{hyperref} \fi
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: +1 for you support. Do I need to replace your code in my cls file? Why the `else` statement is removed? Thanks.

Comment: copy the `thesis.cls` to `mythesis.cls` and change that part of code. For a test put `mythesis.cls` into your documents directory and use `\documentclass{mythesis}`. The else part is not needed because `hyperref`is loaded anyway.

Comment: Always the same error. The log has changed a bit: *[pdfpagelabels,]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [pdftex,pdfa]
Adding the global options:
  pdfpagelabels,,pdftex,pdfa*

Comment: before you load `pdfax` do a `\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}` And do not use the option `pdftex`. Is the `thesis.cls` for download anywhere?

Comment: Well, Does `pdfax` is the same of `pdfx`? I tried to use `\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}` before documentclass, but no chance. I'm not using pdftex option anywhere. I searched in the class but I cannot find it. Now I'm compiling under Windows with **pdfLatex**. I didn't write the class, so I'm not sure I can share it. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I cannot believe that `thesis.cls` is not free available. It is not possible to give help without knowing the internals of the class