# In biblatex (and fnpct) the feature of moving around punctuation breaks if using color commands over it

Tags: biblatex, color, punctuation, fnpct

Biblatex by default (`autopunct = true`) moves punctuations around for superscript citation. However, changing the color of the superscript by `\textcolor` or by `\color` (need extra grouping) breaks this feature.
I noticed this even happens also with `fnpct`.
As can be seen in the MWE all attempts to have a colored superscript after punctuation failed (lines 2 to 4).
Any idea how to solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
    %autopunct = true,  %that is the default setting
    autocite = superscript,
    hyperref=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}  


\NewDocumentCommand\testA{m}{%
    \begingroup\color{blue}\autocite{#1}\endgroup%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand\testB{m}{%
    \color{blue}\autocite{#1}%
}%


\begin{document}

This is a normal test \autocite{loh}. Things after. 

This is an inline with color test \textcolor{blue}{\autocite{loh}}. Things after.

This is a macro test \testA{loh}. Things after. 

This is a macro test \testB{loh}. Things after. 


\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**:
As an example for what I am trying to reproduce:
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41699-019-0098-2.pdf

**EDIT 2:**
To make it more clear: I need one pdf-a version (through pdfx) for archiving and one pdf-x version for printing. Many of hyperref features, including citecolor are disabled with pdf-x and using hyperref `citecolor` option is not possible anymore.
Some more detailss are mentioned here:
[X-4 option of PDFX does not show hyperlink color with the PDF/X option (x-4)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481893/x-4-option-of-pdfx-does-not-show-hyperlink-color-with-the-pdf-x-option-x-4)

Comment: I'm sorry to say this is just how it is. On the implementational level the command needs to absorb the punctuation as an argument. If you wrap it in a pair of braces like in the example, then the punctuation can not be read as an argument to `\autocite` and is ignored.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to colour all footnote markers? Only footnote markers for citations? Do you want to colour all of `biblatex`'s citation outputs? Is `hyperref` involved?

Comment: @moewe, thanks for the reply. Yes I want all biblatex citations (which should be in superscript) to be colored and correctly after punctuations. Examples might be find in many scientific journals, such as here:
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41699-019-0098-2.pdf
And yes, hyperref is involved in the real case (not in MWE). It refs to the entry in the bibliography.

Comment: I'm asking about `hyperref` because a cheap solution might be to just colour all citation links in blue `\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}`. Technically you would not be colouring citations, you would be colouring all linked parts of citations. But in your case this probably coincides.

Comment: @moewe Well, that leads to another caveat which I mentioned here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481893/x-4-option-of-pdfx-does-not-show-hyperlink-color-with-the-pdf-x-option-x-4

In other words, trying to have press-ready pdf one should ignore hyperref `citecolor` option.

Comment: To make it more clear: I need one pdf-a version for archiving and one pdf-x version for printing. Many of hyperref features, including citecolor are disable with pdf-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `\autocite`'s `autopunct` punctuation detection and moving feature works requires that the punctuation follow `\autocite` directly so that it can be absorbed as a final argument. If `\autocite` itself is wrapped in a command, then it can not absorb the punctuation after the wrapper. In theory it would be possible to make the wrapper absorb the punctuation and pass it on to `\autocite`, but I consider it bad practice to write wrapper commands like `\testA` and `\testB` for `biblatex` `\...cite` commands anyway. Instead we can use the wrapper argument to `\DeclareCiteCommand`. The original definition of `\supercite` can be found in `numeric.cbx` and we only change the wrapper

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  autocite = superscript,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}  

\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibcolouredsuperscript}[1]{%
  \textcolor{blue}{%
    \mkbibsuperscript{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibcolouredsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}

\begin{document}
This is a normal test \autocite{loh}. Things after. 

This is an inline with color test \textcolor{blue}{\autocite{loh}}. Things after.
\end{document}
```

[image: Blue supercite marked in expected position.]

---

As I mentioned in the comments, if you use `hyperref` and only want to colour the citation links and not the citation itself

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

might be a nicer solution. But in this case that is out of the question because of `pdfx` features.

---

Addressing the comment. The same general approach works for all styles. But the exact code required may vary since the answer needs the correct definition of teh `\...cite` command. For `numeric-comp` we would need

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibcolouredsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}
```

---

I *absolutely* can not recommend this, but since you asked about it in the comments, here is a solution that shows how you could absorb the punctuation command from after the wrapper and typeset it before `\autocite`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  autocite = superscript,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}  

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\testaAautocite}[2]{%
  #2\unspace
  \textcolor{blue}{\autocite{#1}}}
\newcommand{\testA}[1]{%
  \blx@thecheckpunct{\testaAautocite{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a normal test \autocite{loh}. Things after. 

This is an inline with color test \textcolor{blue}{\autocite{loh}}. Things after.

This is a normal test \testA{loh}. Things after. 

This is a normal test \testA{loh} and non-punctuation afterwards.

This is a normal test \testA{loh}and non-punctuation afterwards.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It works nice. However, If I user `style=numeric-comp` it throws  `Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'cite' undefined.`. It works fine with `style=numeric`.

Also, while I understand your concern "... possible to make the wrapper absorb the punctuation and pass it on to \autocite, but I consider it bad practice to write wrapper commands ..", in my case it gives other possibilities. I convert Asciidoc to Latex and cite keys need some preprocessing before passing to autocite. So, I appreciate if you give some clue how to pass punc to autocite.

Comment: @Shahryar See the edit, please. In case you have to preprocess the cite keys I strongly suggest to do this at an earlier (bit definitely a different) stage than in the document right before passing them to `\autocite`.

Comment: thanks a lot for you complete and perfect answer!